# Neo4J Cypher - subtract duration from timestamp

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a dynamic query which will get me results from "today" (when submitted) and so many days backwards.

Lets say for the sake of the example that I want the last 14 days of data, from today.

The field `first_submitted` is recorded by use of `timestamp()`

I have tried the following code;

```
match(u:data) WHERE u.first_submitted > timestamp()}-duration('P14D') AND u.first_submitted < timestamp() RETURN u.first_submitted LIMIT 10
```

However I receive the error

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError: Cannot subtract `Duration` from `Long`
```

I tried a few different ways of coding this but am turning up very confused with the syntax and Neo4J's documentation surrounding this.

Alternatively, if you can think of a better way to do this that isn't resource too heavy please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I'm not sure what the "data.apoch" stuff I keep seeing is exactly but when I try to run any of these commands I receive errors so if I can avoid the need of this library please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Yes, the temporal values and functions are pretty complex, and the documentation is scattered and dense.*

The [timestamp](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-timestamp) function returns an integer. But a [Duration](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/#cypher-temporal-durations) (which can be constructed using the [duration](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/temporal/duration/) function) can only be subtracted from a [temporal instant](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/#cypher-temporal-instants) (for example, a `DateTime`, which can be constructed using the [datetime](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/temporal/time/#functions-datetime) function).

So, for simplicity, the `first_submitted` property value should be something like a `DateTime` (which represents a date and time) instead of an integer. For example:

```
CREATE (:data {id: 123, first_submitted: datetime()})
```

Assuming that is true, your query could look like this:

```
WITH datetime()-duration('P14D') AS threshold
MATCH (u:data)
WHERE u.first_submitted > threshold
RETURN u.first_submitted LIMIT 10
```

Note: it is not necessary to test that the stored DateTime is *before* the current DateTime, since presumably all `first_submitted` values are in the past.

Also, you may want to create an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) on `:data(first_submitted)` to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks @cybersam, you mentioned 'for simplicity use `DateTime` value instead' but any thoughts on the difference in server performance with this change? Thanks.

Comment: If you store a `DateTime`, then your queries can avoid having to convert epoch times to `DateTime`s. That is more efficient, and simplifies your logic.